# formatexception (formatexception: unexpected character (at character 1) json

Tags: php, mysql, json, mobile, flutter

[image: **enter image description here**]

The error as stated is:
formatexception (formatexception: unexpected character (at character 1) json
Is there a solution to this?

Comment: try to print(response.body); and see the output. It may not be valid JSON

Comment: i try it but doesn't work. So does the problem came from invalid JSON or from the php side?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one bro

```
final response = await http.post("url", body{
  'username': username,
  'password': password,
},
header{
  'accept':'*/*'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the Exception, you are getting HTML code instead of JSON in the response.body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "~//W3C/DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org...
```

The solution would be to receive a JSON or to try to parse the HTML