# FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1) <!DOCTYPE html> Flutter Google Sheets

Tags: json, flutter, dart, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm getting this weird response while using `http` in `Flutter/Dart`. Similar code is working fine with other *APIs* endpoints but not this. Although the link has `jSON` data not any other format.

I have already check the following links and NONE of them is related to mine:

- [formatexception (formatexception: unexpected character (at character 1) json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264028/formatexception-formatexception-unexpected-character-at-character-1-json)
- [Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348703/exception-formatexception-unexpected-character-at-character-1)

### Exception

[image]

### Explanation

The exception I'm getting is similar. And I know that it is return `HTML` instead of `jSON`. But my link is **NOT** an `HTML`. Its a array of `jSON Objects`

[image]

### Code

#### Apps Script Code for Google Sheets

```dart
function doGet(request) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1CBPpqvdUpPaYMjxpX_9-ywMsErT06fD6AfzASWBFnnk");

  var values = sheet.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var data = [];

  for (var i = values.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var row = values[i];
    var story = {};

    story['Latitude'] = row[5];
    story['Longitude'] = row[6];
    console.log(story['Longitude'], story['Longitude']);

    data.push(story);
  }

  return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(data))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

#### Model Class

```dart
class StoryList {
  final List<Story> stories;

  StoryList({this.stories});

  factory StoryList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
    List<Story> story = new List<Story>();
    story = parsedJson.map((i) => Story.fromJSON(i)).toList();
    return new StoryList(stories: story);
  }
}

class Story {
  final String longitude;
  final String latitude;

  Story({this.latitude, this.longitude});

  factory Story.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Story(
      longitude: json['Longitude'],
      latitude: json['Latitude'],
    );
  }
}
```

### Controller Class

*You won't be able to access the `link` its restricted for organization use only*

```dart
class StoryController {
  Future<StoryList> getCountryData() async {
    String url =
        'https://script.google.com/a/macros/storius.app/s/AKfycbyzx4kIlVdTC9QVVBovVfWMDFWdk9noomDJV4XcyDApnsMYTe68u0mL/exec';
    final response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonRes = json.decode(response.body);
      return StoryList.fromJson(jsonRes);
    } else {
      throw Exception("Failed due to Network Error");
    }
  }
}
```

#### View Class

For the time being I'm only getting `Longitude` for testing purposes.

```dart
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeViewState createState() => _HomeViewState();
}

class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
      future: StoryController().getCountryData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(snapshot.data.stories[index].longitude),
                );
              });
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our Discord discussion, when you printed response.body at my suggestion you see that you are getting an html response from the url, not json as you expected.

The problem is with authentication on the linked website rather than with the Flutter/Dart code. You need to resolve that authentication issue.

It is recommended that when testing new code that accesses a database or a url to always print out, or use a debugger to view, the returned data. Never assume you are getting what you expect.

Comment: Thank you, actually you are right. But can you help me how to resolve this auth issue? Although I have made the link public this time. Yet its not working

Update: I got the answer, I need to pass `accessToken` in response header after getting gmail auth.
Thanks buddy you did great :)